# Door newly out of plane - just winter weather or bad framing?

Tags: doors, door-frame, frame, winter

My front door is out of plane - the top left corner does not sit completely in the frame. The funny thing is this is brand new. We've lived in the house for two years and it just started this winter. That makes me wonder - is this something where I should be readjusting the hinges as is typically the case with out of plane doors, or is this something that's a result of winter weather that will resolve itself in a couple weeks? I don't want to change the hinges and then have it be too tight when the spring comes!

Comment: Location?  ***Unusually*** cold weather? Age of house?

Comment: How well sealed (paint, varnish) is the door? Top and bottom edges as well?

Comment: Virginia. We've had very cold weather from that polar vortex. Painted door. Just top - enough that two or three times I've had to push it in with my shoulder to lock the deadbolt.

Comment: House built mid-sixties. It's block with stucco on the block. I don't think the door or door frame is that old. I know the previous owner redid the windows and I believe the door too.

Comment: And like I said, it was hanging fine until this winter.

Comment: is it a wood, vinyl, steel or fiberglass door?  Was it prehung?

Comment: Wood door. I don't know if it was pre-hung. Is there a way to tell if it was pre-hung if it was already installed when we moved in?

Comment: I there snow sitting on the roof of your home?The weight of snow can cause deflection of the roof which is attached to the walls that you door is mounted into.

Answer (score 1):

Most units are prehung. If the mortises on the jam and door look perfect and fit precisely, it is usually a prehung.  Unless the situation is intolerable, I'd give it a while and let conditions change before making drastic changes to the door or hinge sets. I suspect possible settling or drastic humidity or temperature  related expansion to the frame. You should also check to assure all the hung screw are snug. If you have a good 6 foot level, you can compare plumb between the door and frame on both sides to determine if a side has moved or lay the level against the door and look for any bow, gaps etc.   An other test is to remove the door (just remove hinge pins) and check that it has not warped by laying it on a known flat surface and look for gaps or rocking indicating that the door may have warped. Sometimes very hard to see a small wain by eye when hung.